# Trying to remove the download button on Wordpress Native Video Player?

Tags: video-player

Can I remove the download button in the Wordpress Native Video Player? I don't want to encourage people to download my video's.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the default behavior of how the browser renders HTML5 video.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115801/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video) you should be able to use the following CSS to *hide* the button.

```
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

Comment: That is great Jared.
But I don't know what to do with this code.

Comment: Edit the style.css file of your theme. Make sure that you are working on a child theme, since your customization will be discarded by the next version of the theme your are using. It works like a charm for me. Thanks for your input Jared.